# How to change date format ONLY in first column in .csv file using sed in shell

Tags: csv, unix, sed

Hello I am trying to change the date format only in first column of .csv file 
from:

> 2015-03-31|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.225|3.225|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   2015-03-31|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.225|3.225|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   2015-03-31|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.225|3.225|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   2015-03-31|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.225|3.225|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   2015-03-31|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.475|3.475|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   2015-03-31|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.475|3.475|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   2015-03-31|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.475|3.475|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   2015-03-31|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.475|3.475|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   2015-03-31|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.475|3.475|0|0|0|2015-03-31

TO:

> 03/31/2015|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.225|3.225|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   03/31/2015|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.225|3.225|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   03/31/2015|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.225|3.225|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   03/31/2015|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.225|3.225|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   03/31/2015|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.475|3.475|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   03/31/2015|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.475|3.475|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   03/31/2015|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.475|3.475|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   03/31/2015|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.475|3.475|0|0|0|2015-03-31
>   03/31/2015|base|2015-03-31|100|0|3.475|3.475|0|0|0|2015-03-31

I have tried using sed :

```
sed 's/^\(....\-\)\(..\-\)(..|\)/\2\1\3/'
```

and

```
sed -re 's/^([0-9][0-9])\-([0-9][0-9])\-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9](.*)$/\2\/\1\/\3\4/'
```

but it's throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two attempts were very close. The command:

```
  sed 's/\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\)/\2\/\3\/\1/'
```

should work. And one could bullet-proof it by replacing each dot `.` by `[0-9]`, and adding an initial `^`.

A variant, which removes eight of the eleven backslashes, is:

```
  sed -r 's_(....)-(..)-(..)_\2/\3/\1_'
```

Here the underscore `_` could be replaced by some other character.

Comment: Thanks . But how does it know to only take first column of it and ignore rest?

Comment: It does the _first_ match. This is hopefully in the first column. But if your CSV file has more variation than shown, you might want to add a `^`,